# Android Studio debugger stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I'm not being able to debug my app as after setting a breakpoint and debugger stops at it, it then stops suddenly after two or three seconds and app exits with no aparent reason.

I've tried setting the breakpoint at different locations to ensure no other background process is interfering with it, for example at the very beginning of onCreate in splash activity, but the same happens, debugger stops as expected and after a few seconds app exits and debugging session ends unexpectedly.

I've tried updating Android Studio and Gradle to latest version (my AS is 3.6.1) and Gradle 5.6.4 (plugin version is 3.6.1) to no avail. Also tried uninstalling/reinstalling the app to no avail too and lastly I've tried "Invalidate caches and restart" option in Android Studio but it neither worked.

I'm not being able to debug and don't know what else to try / do.

My mobile is a Huawei Mate 20 Lite, and I've also tried rebooting the phone with no success.

Here is my "Logcat" as soon as debugger stops and app exits (app figures as com.mycompany.myapp):

```
2020-03-06 19:20:39.719 1408-1432/? E/WindowManager: icon is null!!
2020-03-06 19:20:39.722 1408-1432/? E/WindowManager: icon is null!!
2020-03-06 19:20:39.724 1408-1432/? E/WindowManager: icon is null!!
2020-03-06 19:20:39.777 2462-5966/? E/HwNaturalBase: [Binder:2462_10]: clearDataByOwner ignore: Found null values with the given ownerPkgName is[com.mycompany.myapp].
2020-03-06 19:20:39.778 2334-4531/? E/AwareLog: GameSdkConfigReader: GameSdkLog: idNameMap: null
2020-03-06 19:20:39.809 847-861/? E/AwareLog: iawared: GetFileContent open /proc/14267/task/14277/cpuset fail errno(2)!
2020-03-06 19:20:39.815 14269-14269/? E/ssioncontrolle: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-03-06 19:20:39.817 838-838/? E/Thermal-daemon: [shell_frame] temp_new :29  temp_old :28
2020-03-06 19:20:39.817 1408-1927/? E/ProcessInfoCollector: getProcessInfo: failed to find this proc 
2020-03-06 19:20:39.818 838-838/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [shell_frame] temp :29  report_threshold:1
2020-03-06 19:20:39.820 838-838/? E/Thermal-daemon: [ap] temp_new :36  temp_old :35
2020-03-06 19:20:39.821 838-838/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [ap] temp :36  report_threshold:1
2020-03-06 19:20:39.855 3259-3259/? E/NfcNci: NfcUtils error: APP do not have nfc permission
2020-03-06 19:20:39.857 3259-3259/? E/NfcNci: NfcUtils error: APP do not have nfc permission
2020-03-06 19:20:39.865 2033-2033/? E/HwLauncher: PowerSaveLauncherModel onPackageChanged: not inPowerSaveLauncher 
2020-03-06 19:20:39.865 2033-2033/? E/HwLauncher: StreetModeLauncherModel onPackageChanged: not inStreetModeLauncher 
2020-03-06 19:20:39.889 653-1175/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLauncher#1]:1338: disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-03-06 19:20:39.890 653-2692/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLauncher#0]:1338: disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-03-06 19:20:39.908 642-642/? E/WifiHAL: enter wifi_get_link_stats
2020-03-06 19:20:39.912 1408-1610/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: 0, Chload: -1
2020-03-06 19:20:39.942 577-14300/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (123, <unspecified>/0)
2020-03-06 19:20:42.444 1408-8027/? E/WifiService: enforceCanAccessScanResults: hiding ssid and bssidLocation mode is disabled for the device
2020-03-06 19:20:42.456 1408-1602/? E/WifiService: enforceCanAccessScanResults: hiding ssid and bssidLocation mode is disabled for the device
2020-03-06 19:20:42.468 2033-2033/? E/HwLauncher: HwAppMarketDownloadModel handleInstallAction op: 2
2020-03-06 19:20:42.663 7452-7525/? E/HSM_UI: SecurityBroadcastReceiver:SecurityBroadcastReceiver the rainbow is not enabled!
2020-03-06 19:20:42.789 577-14311/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (123, <unspecified>/0)
2020-03-06 19:20:42.956 642-642/? E/WifiHAL: enter wifi_get_link_stats
2020-03-06 19:20:42.963 1408-1610/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: 0, Chload: -1
2020-03-06 19:20:43.173 653-2692/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Waiting For Debugger: com.mycompany.myapp#0]:1338: disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-03-06 19:20:43.185 1408-7773/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{d9a7484 u0 Waiting For Debugger: com.mycompany.myapp} has no registered input channel
2020-03-06 19:20:43.201 1408-2090/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{d9a7484 u0 Waiting For Debugger: com.mycompany.myapp} has no registered input channel
2020-03-06 19:20:43.611 14186-14323/com.mycompany.myapp E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@563b55d
2020-03-06 19:20:43.616 14186-14323/com.mycompany.myapp E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@fa4bed2
2020-03-06 19:20:43.650 577-14328/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (123, <unspecified>/0)
2020-03-06 19:20:44.824 838-838/? E/Thermal-daemon: [ap] temp_new :37  temp_old :36
2020-03-06 19:20:44.828 838-838/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [ap] temp :37  report_threshold:1
2020-03-06 19:20:45.312 1408-1610/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: 0, Chload: -1
2020-03-06 19:20:45.842 8205-10507/? E/HSC_SEC: VirusPkgParser:parse InputStream is null
2020-03-06 19:20:45.985 642-642/? E/WifiHAL: enter wifi_get_link_stats
2020-03-06 19:20:45.987 1408-1610/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: 0, Chload: -1
2020-03-06 19:20:46.733 879-996/? E/ScreemCommon: <LOGMGR> <logCaptureFilter> [not the beta version or delimitation frozen, no need to capture log]
2020-03-06 19:20:46.733 879-996/? E/ScreemCommon: ### JankSchedHwRead error!
2020-03-06 19:20:46.734 879-996/? E/ScreemCommon: ### ScreemSchedDlmRead read failed!
2020-03-06 19:20:46.735 879-996/? E/ScreemCommon: ### ScreemSchedDlmRead error!
2020-03-06 19:20:46.737 879-996/? E/ScreemCommon: update dlm info failed
2020-03-06 19:20:46.996 2258-2450/? E/HwCHRWifiRSSIGroupSummery: updatArpSummery mRSSI:-1  HwCHRWifiRSSIGroup [rssi_index=4, rtt_tcp_packets=0, rtt_tcp_duration=0, rtt_lan_duration=5066, rtt_lan_failures=0, rtt_lan_succ=396, rtt_lan_max=324, rtt_lan_min=4,same_area_frequency=0,adjacent_area_frequency=0]
2020-03-06 19:20:47.212 2258-2258/? E/CHR_ChrModemStatistics: sensors invalid
2020-03-06 19:20:47.471 2334-17416/? E/AppInfoMgr: not find pkgs by uid: 0
2020-03-06 19:20:49.008 642-642/? E/WifiHAL: enter wifi_get_link_stats
2020-03-06 19:20:49.013 1408-1610/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: 0, Chload: -1
2020-03-06 19:20:49.393 1408-1431/? E/ActivityTaskManager: app boot failure event send
2020-03-06 19:20:49.443 879-3232/? E/LOGSERVER_UTILS: [ZeroHung]sentEvent: result->scope length:3, wpName length:2
2020-03-06 19:20:49.443 879-3232/? E/LOGSERVER_UTILS: [ZeroHung]sentEvent: recoverSolution length:10, recoverResult length:7, keyLog length:31
2020-03-06 19:20:49.479 879-3232/? E/iMonitor: [ZeroHung]appendFile: open /data/log/reliability/appeye/history.log.0 failed
2020-03-06 19:20:49.484 879-998/? E/ScreemHealth: Get an unregisted msg 3.
2020-03-06 19:20:49.512 1408-1587/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{c946538 u0 com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLauncher} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false
2020-03-06 19:20:49.512 1408-1587/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{b8371be u0 com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLauncher} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false
2020-03-06 19:20:49.533 2334-4108/? E/AwareLog: SPKSchedFeature: Uid has been sent, ignore.
2020-03-06 19:20:49.602 1408-1587/? E/ZRHungService: BF and NFW forceStop package: com.mycompany.myapp
2020-03-06 19:20:49.630 3259-3259/? E/NfcNci: NfcUtils error: APP do not have nfc permission
2020-03-06 19:20:49.637 1899-4895/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
2020-03-06 19:20:49.637 2334-4531/? E/AwareLog: GameSdkConfigReader: GameSdkLog: idNameMap: null
2020-03-06 19:20:49.638 3259-3259/? E/NfcNci: NfcUtils error: APP do not have nfc permission
2020-03-06 19:20:49.652 21186-21228/? E/AppLifeChangeSensor: CAWARENESS: activityResumed mAppLifeChangeCallback is null 
2020-03-06 19:20:49.653 1899-11648/? E/DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLauncher state:2 fg:true mUid:10074
2020-03-06 19:20:49.657 1408-1432/? E/WindowManager: icon is null!!
2020-03-06 19:20:49.832 838-838/? E/Thermal-daemon: [ap] temp_new :36  temp_old :37
2020-03-06 19:20:49.833 838-838/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [ap] temp :36  report_threshold:1
2020-03-06 19:20:50.168 21235-14119/? E/TotemWeather: DeviceStateServiceListener:lastLocation is null
```

Edit 1:

Inspecting Logcat I can guess that maybe "ZRHungService" is causing the problem, but cannot find any information about this service.

```
E/ZRHungService: BF and NFW forceStop package: com.mycompany.myapp
```

Edit 2:

I've tried debugging in a virtual device with success, but the problem is I'm debugging the copy of a file in downloads to cache dir and in virtual device I don't have that file, so I think that's not an option :(

Comment: "debugger stops at it, it then stops suddenly after two or three seconds" , this is called an ANR, Activity Not Responding, because of your breakpoint.

Comment: And what do I do with that @Blundell? I'm having problems and I need to debug.
I'm not seeing any "ANR" info on screen like it says here BTW: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr

Comment: Yeah usually a dialog comes up and you can say "ignore".

Comment: I definitely don't think it's an ANR @Blundell. I see an ANR alert when my app is able to debug and it is stopped for a long time, but not it's happening something different, no ANR popup (with "Wait" and "Close" buttons) is shown, the app just exits and debugger stops.

Comment: Try using an emulator instead of that phone. Huawei might have made it work funkily

Comment: OK @Blundell, I can debug with emulator, didn't realize it's an option, but that's not the case; i've been always debugging with my phone with no problems and I really need to find a solution.
Anyway, thanks for your help, at least I can debug now.

Comment: So it sounds like a Huawei problem. Have a look in the developer options, see if there's anything you can turn off to do with ANR's, or turn on to do with Debugging

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Blundell. I've already inspecting that. Plenty of options but none seems to be related to that, or at least I was not able to find the correct one.
For the moment I'm following your suggestion and debugging with a virtual device successfully, but honestly I'll have to find a slution to that.
Anyway and for now, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same problem with last version of Android Studio and I am debugging in a Samsung S20 phone. Unfortunately, I cannot use the emulator since the whole computer get very very slow. My PC processor is Intel i5 with 8 GB of memory. It seems in order to use Android emulator, a super computer is needed. Did you find the solution to the debugging session problem? It is definetly not an ANR problem, because I can place a breakpoint in other place of the activity and it can wait for ever.

Comment: Hi @jstuardo. It's been a while not developing in Android, and many Android Studio and Huawei updates, so I cannot say, and maybe the problem has gone for me, but don't know exactly.

Answer (score 11):

I am getting the same issue if anyone from Huawei, or users of them have found real solutions yet. It's only just started happening on my Mate 20 Pro since it was updated to Android 10 a few days ago.

Here are my logcat lines for the app. Dies after 3-4 secs of being on a breakpoint :

```
2020-03-10 20:22:24.228 711-981/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Waiting For Debugger: digital.key.testapp#0]:1338: disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2020-03-10 20:22:24.249 1108-2438/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{b4506fa u0 Waiting For Debugger: digital.key.testapp} has no registered input channel
2020-03-10 20:22:24.422 8057-8106/digital.key.testapp E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@77e0f7
2020-03-10 20:22:30.622 1108-1817/? E/ZRHungService: BF and NFW forceStop package: digital.key.testapp
```

I have found one temporary solution. Set a debug app in your devleoper options on your phone and tell it to wait for debugger. Then launch it and you can attach the debugger from Android Studio and all works well.

- Settings -> System and Updates -> Developer Options
- Under Debugging find 'Select debug app' and choose your app
- Tick ON 'Wait for debugger'
- Run app from app drawer
- In Android Studio choose attach debugger instead and breakpoints no longer crash

[image: Dev Options Select debug app].

Comment: Thank you very much @Captain Wizard. I'll try your solution as soon as I can. Unfortunately seems more like a workaround, but if it does work, at least is kinda a temporary solution until the debugger starts working again. I'm starting to guess is something related to some update in Huawei.

Comment: Hope you have some good luck with it. From what i've seen I'm getting a 75% success when doing it this way. It's clunky, and annoying, but if you need to debug on a real device is at least an option. For me its definitely something they have done with my new 10 update, as I used to debug on 9 with no issues.

Comment: Unfortunately the workaround doesn't work for me with Android Studio 4.1.3 on Mate 9 with Android 9.  Basically the app restarts after I step through a couple breakpoints.

Comment: On Honor 10 it works weirdly. In settings I select a needed app, turn on waiting for debugger, run the app. It waits for Android Studio, I press "Attach debugger to Android process" button. Then it works. But If I don't attach a debugger every time, it crashes. For instance, when try to start a debug from AS (Shift + F9).

Answer (score 0):

**Huawei Mate 20 Lite solution** 
I don't know how and why does this work, it's not a scientific method.
For those who doesn't work Captain Wizard's solution, I have found a weird approach for this issue. Some requirments presented above should be considered.

1. Normal run the app
2. As fast as you can, go to Run -> Attach to process.. You have to choose this option from the run menu, **NOT** "Attach Debugger to Android Process" as it will not work.
3. A pop-up appears, choose the option that appears.
4. Something finally shows up, don't pay attention to it.
5. Choose "Attach Debugger to Android Process" icon.
6. Now, the debugging process should not stop after a few seconds.

Comment: Probably it works on Huawei, but on Honor 10 it shows 2 processes: KotlinCompileDaemon and GradleDaemon. After selecting any, it won't debug without crash.