# Why does Android Studio kill processes after ~5 seconds while stopped in the debugger?

Tags: android, android-studio

While debugging my android application, I will frequently use breakpoints to pause code execution and inspect variable values (as we all do). Unfortunately, I seem to only have between 5-10 seconds to view the values and step or resume execution. If I wait any longer, Android Studio (or the Android OS, I am not sure which) will seem to kill my application, thereby causing me to lose all of the state I was just inspecting and requiring me to start execution all over again.

I see this link: [Android Studio debugger stops unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569758/android-studio-debugger-stops-unexpectedly)

However I have been experiencing this behavior for years, on both hardware devices and the emulator.

Can anyone explain the cause of this behavior and offer a solution?

Comment: FWIW, I just put a breakpoint in a reasonably-complex app and was able to sit there for over a minute without the process being terminated. This was even a breakpoint on the main application thread. So, your results are not universal. Note that the debugger might not suspend all threads when you hit a breakpoint, so if you are blocking some thread that another thread is dependent upon, that might cause some sort of timeout that causes problems for you.

Answer (score 3):

Those who are facing this problem, the temparary solution is to add your app in **debug app**

> `Under Debugging find 'Select debug app' and choose your app`

For more details please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569758/android-studio-debugger-stops-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

Per the insights from @CommonsWare, I believe Android Studio was killing my process while debugging because, in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, I had the following line:

```
        <service
            android:name=".services.appevents.AppEventService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

By commenting out this section, I was able to avoid having the debugger proactively kill my application process.